# A procedure imported by {myassembly} could not be loaded

Tags: c#, debugging, assemblies

when running a prorgam, it seems that I am missing a library, when I launch the output of my project I get an exception at startup.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: A procedure imported by 'my assembly, Version=xx.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7292581204d9e04a' could not be loaded.

'ScriptX.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', No symbols loaded.
```

My question is: how can I determine which library is missing because, at this point, I cannot see the values passed to:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) + 0x3a bytes
```

Comment: The German translation reads "**Eine von {myassembly} importierte Prozedur konnte nicht geladen werden.**", just in case someone is googling this (just like I did).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is in fact a built in mechanism for just these diagnostics.

(1) In your project properties/Debug, make sure 'Enable native code debugging' is checked:

[image]

(2) Raise the [show-loader-snaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556886(v=vs.85).aspx) flag  - it is a registry key in the IFEO, and is accessible via the 'GlobalFlags' GUI:

[image]

(3) Run the app from a debugger - or attach before the load error. Inspect the (*very*) verbose output pane. You can mostly skip to the end or look for 'ERROR'.

More details [here](http://ofekshilon.com/2013/06/22/entry-point-not-found-and-other-dll-loading-problems/).

Comment: We had two devs banging their heads against a problem and this pointed us straight to the answer.  Thank you!

Comment: I just wanted to add that I could find that error only when attached to the process using `windbg`.

Comment: App needs to be run under a debugger (e.g. Visual studio, windbg or cdb) to see debug output.

Comment: In the Image field, only the exe file name should be entered, not the full path. Just to help out others who gets stuck because of it.

Answer (score 8):

Are you doing any dllimport? - this looks like an issue with an unmanaged dll not being found?

First thing is to ensure that any unmanaged dll's or exe's that you are calling into (via dllimport) are deployed into the same folder as the .Net exe that you are building

If the source of the calling assembly is not available you could try using [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) on that assembly to search for dllimport statements

Other than that you might want to enable the fustion log viewer to trace assembly load issues - see this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx) and [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309346(VS.71).aspx) for more details

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to the source of this DLL. If there is any way to determine what assembly failed to be loaded it would be of a great help.

Comment: Thank you Richard, the two links were very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Implement a handler for the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event.  It tells you which assembly it is looking for with ResolveEventArgs.Name.  If this is just an effort to troubleshoot this particular assembly then use Fuslogvw.exe.  If the hangup is an unmanaged assembly then DependencyWalker's Profile option can show you what LoadLibrary() call is failing.  SysInternals' ProcMon will work too but is a lot noisier.

Comment: Thank you for yoru reply, I chose Richard's reply because I just looked at his posts and managed to use fusiion logs.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases when using COM, you might just need to unregister and reregister the dll with RegAsm.exe. 
That is what fixed this issue for me last week, things had gotten out of sync.