# Getting error "A procedure imported by xxxxxxxx.dll cannot be loaded

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting "A procedure imported by xxxxxxx.dll cannot be loaded, while I am trying to run my .net application from browser. Below is what I am getting:

```
[FileLoadException: A procedure imported by 'xxxxxxx.DLL' could not be loaded.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +39
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +132
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +144
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46

[ConfigurationErrorsException: A procedure imported by 'xxxxxxxxx.DLL' could not be loaded.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +618
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +209
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +178
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +94
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +332
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +677

[HttpException (0x80004005): A procedure imported by 'xxxxxxxx.DLL' could not be loaded.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9088636
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +258
```

Is there is any way to find out which procedure it is not able to load or any other way to solve the issue. I tried Fusion logs and there seems to be no issue in Fusion logs.

Thank for help.

Comment: There are a couple of suggestions here to try too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945589/a-procedure-imported-by-myassembly-could-not-be-loaded

Comment: Thank you. But I already saw this post and that couldn't resolve my issue. Also the dll which is in error is an Unmanaged assembly.

Comment: @Maverick: Running under full trust?

Comment: @Maverick: Try force that and see if the error persists :)

Comment: @leppie I tried it and still no luck. The dll is an unmanaged dll. Do you think that could be causing an issue?

Comment: @Maverick that is most definitely the case. But there should be a way to do it. IIRC you can run COM components in the browser, so it should be possible. Just have no idea how :) Good luck (and  +1 for inspiration)