# LoadLibrary() error code 1008

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, matlab-deployment, loadlibrary, error-code

I want to load a C++ dll in C# (VS2012, C++ dll also created in VS2012 C++) that in C++ dll I've used a shared library generated by MATLAB with using of deploytool.(My configuration in both C# and C++ programs is x64 and shared library also generated in 64-bit version of MATLAB).
I've used following codes to load library and then I've recieved error code 1008 :

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll",CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string libname);
...
IntPtr handle = LoadLibrary("libName.dll");
if(handle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
   int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
   //at this point error code will be 1008.
}
```

Help me to resolve that, please!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: when i insert a break point at  `if(handle == IntPtr.Zero)`  line and then continue I recieve error code 1008 and when I run without any breakpoints recived error code will be 193. But, as in above-mentioned all the programs that I use are in x64 configuration or are 64-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

Good chance the failure isn't directly in libName.dll but rather in one of its dependencies. There are quite a few tools that diagnose such dll loading problems:

1. [Process monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) file system activity, can show you if a dll is sought but not found.
2. [Dependency walker's 'profile' option](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/hidm_execute.htm) can show you *which* dependent dll failed to load.
3. The most powerful tool AFAIK: 'Show Snaps' checkbox in gflags (bundled with debugging tools for windows).  It activates a windows-loader-built-in tracing facility, that shows you not only who failed to load but also why exactly. Some more details and screenshots [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24652463/89706).