# Registering DLL in another folder

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reflection

I have a small console application which backs up and then copies new DLLs to an installation folder, and then is supposed to re-register the new DLLs. It can also restore DLLs from a backup and then re-register the backups.

I have the following code to perform the registeration:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(options.RemotePath), Path.GetFileName(file)));
RegistrationServices regAsm = new RegistrationServices();
bool bResult = regAsm.RegisterAssembly(asm, AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase);
```

I'm having a problem with registering where on calling Assembly.LoadFrom I get a `System.IO.FileLoadException` with the message `A procedure imported by 'MyLib.dll' could not be loaded`

I thought this was probably a DLL in the remote folder that it was unable to load, so I wrapped my registration code in a change of current directory:

```
var wd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(options.RemotePath);
...
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(wd);
```

Unfortunately this didn't seem to resolve the issue. I did some more investigating and found that I can tell the AppDomain how to resolve dependencies using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` and `ResolveEventHandler`, and so I set this up by adding this code at the beginning of `Main`, before my registration code.

```
var otherCompanyDlls = new DirectoryInfo(options.RemotePath).GetFiles("*.dll");

Console.WriteLine("Setting AssemblyResolve");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler((sender, a) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Looking for {0}", a.Name);
    var dll = otherCompanyDlls.FirstOrDefault(fi => fi.Name == a.Name);
    if (dll == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return Assembly.LoadFrom(dll.FullName);
});
```

I still get the same error, and this `AssemblyResolve` handler code never seems to be triggered since the Console line I added is never written.

What is it that I am doing wrong? I was hoping to at least find out what DLL dependency it was trying to load but I can't even seem to find that.

Comment: You may want to try fuslogvw to see which assembly is failing to load.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24652463/9239792), it seems to offer a way to figure out what is wrong.